# Having issues appending tuples to an list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists with line numbers of start and end of specific feeds from a text file:
`startPosOfFeeds = [1, 35]` and `endPosOfFeeds = [34, 56]`
I want to transform these two lists into an list of tuples like this:
`list_of_tuples = [(1,34), (35, 56)]`

Given that I would perform the above operation only if `len(startPosOfFeeds) == len(endPosOfFeeds)`

My Code:

```
numOfFeeds = len(startPosOfFeeds)
print(numOfFeeds)
print(startPosOfFeeds)
print(endPosOfFeeds)

for i in range(numOfFeeds):
    list_of_tuples = []
    print(i)
    print(str(startPosOfFeeds[i])+'......'+str(endPosOfFeeds[i]))
    list_of_tuples.append(startPosOfFeeds[i],endPosOfFeeds[i])
print(list_of_tuples)
```

Incorrect output:

```
2
[1, 35]
[34, 56]
0
1......34
1
35......56
[(35, 56)]
```

I am not sure why the list `list_of_tuples` only holds the last appended value.

Comment: It's a `list` not an `array`. I hope you don't mind that I edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Both the question and the answer will throw a `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument`

Comment: @JaredGoguen Good catch, at least the answer is now corrected :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an empty list each iteration:

```
for i in range(numOfFeeds):
    list_of_tuples = []   # <-- this creates the empty list in each iteration
    ...
    list_of_tuples.append((startPosOfFeeds[i],endPosOfFeeds[i]))
```

The solution is quite simple: Put the `list_of_tuples = []` in front of the loop:

```
list_of_tuples = []
for i in range(numOfFeeds):
    ...
    list_of_tuples.append((startPosOfFeeds[i],endPosOfFeeds[i]))
```

---

Note that you could also use `zip` and a list-comprehension instead:

```
list_of_tuples = [(startpos, endpos) for startpos, endpos in zip(startPosOfFeeds, endPosOfFeeds)]
```

Or just cast the `zip` to a `list`:

```
list_of_tuples = list(zip(startPosOfFeeds, endPosOfFeeds))
```